# keyboard keys acting up

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I've had a strange thing happen to my keyboard on my laptop.

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> puts an `l` on screen followed by an actual `enter`.

<kbd>↓</kbd> (Down key) displays `9` and moves cursor down.

Pressing <kbd>space</kbd> outputs a fullstop followed by a space.

How do I fix this?

Comment: It's all a guess based on the info here. Check that you don't have a virus. That's sure what it sounds like.

Comment: Have you tried a different (USB) keyboard?

Comment: Have't. tried. usb. laptop. . good. idea. . on. screen. keyboard. works. ok

Comment: I see someone else had the same problem

Mine is also a HP 

http://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/152676-keyboard-keys-mixed-up.html

Comment: USB keyboard works just fine